Docker: Postres initialization scripts is unable to run due to role "postgres" does not exist error
I'm trying to create a custom image with Postgres and pg_net, I've been able to set up the installation but having problem running my initialization scripts as I keep getting role "postgres" does not exist error.
I'm passing a custom user to the POSTGRES_USER environment variable as you can see in my code below. How do I get the initialization script to not run as postgres user or how do I even get it to work in general?
Dockerfile
FROM postgres:16-alpine3.19

RUN apk -U add \
  alpine-sdk \
  curl-dev \
  clang15 \
  llvm15 \
  perl \
  && git clone https://github.com/supabase/pg_net.git \
  && cd pg_net \
  && make \
  && make install

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    build: 
      context: .    
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    command: postgres -c shared_preload_libraries=pg_net -c pg_net.database_name=${POSTGRES_DB}; -c max_connections=200
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/initialize-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initialize-db.sh
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  postgres_data:

scripts/initialize-db.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
create extension if not exists pg_net;
EOSQL

Just to confirm that my setup works.
I remove the initialization scripts, ran the image and attached a shell to it where I ran the code below in my psql shell and it worked perfectly.
create extension if not exists pg_net;

